# django debug doesn't print set because of unicode chars (python3)

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

**UPDATE : i'm trying to find example as easy as possible**

**HINT!** I missed, that one person isn't show on the list too! And when I changed it's name - everything is ok - the problem is with unicode char, if there's non-ascii char in string to debug, logger doesn't print at all. In Python2 there were an error, in Python3 unicode is a default so I doesn't thought about it - but somehow it doesn't work. If I use `logger.debug('1: %r' % ascii(suspected))` it's almost good but i want `<Person: TADEUSZ KOŚCIUSZKO>` instead of `<Person: TADEUSZ KO\\u015aCIUSZKO>`

```
  logger.debug('begin')
  suspected = Person.objects.all()
  logger.debug('0')
  try:
    logger.debug('1: %r' % suspected)
  except:
    logger.debug('crash1')
  for sus in suspected:
     logger.debug('2: %r' % sus)
  try:
    logger.debug('3: %r' % suspected)
  except:
    logger.debug('crash4')
  logger.debug('end')
```

result:

```
2016-01-16 08:53:54,665 DEBUG views begin
2016-01-16 08:53:54,667 DEBUG views 0
2016-01-16 08:53:54,938 DEBUG views 2: <Person: JOHN SMITH>
2016-01-16 08:53:55,040 DEBUG views 2: <Person: GEORGE WASHINGTON>
2016-01-16 08:53:55,222 DEBUG views 2: <Person: ABRAHAM LINCOLN>
2016-01-16 08:53:55,253 DEBUG views 2: <Person: PARIS HILTON>
2016-01-16 08:53:55,282 DEBUG views 2: <Person: JOHN WAYNE>
2016-01-16 08:53:55,368 DEBUG views 2: <Person: TEST TEST>
2016-01-16 08:53:55,700 DEBUG views end
```

And why there's no:

```
2016-01-16 08:53:54     DEBUG views 1: [<Person: JOHN SMITH>, <Person: GEORGE WASHINGTON>, <Person: ABRAHAM LINCOLN>, <Person: PARIS HILTON>, <Person: JOHN WAYNE>, <Person: TEST TEST>
```

AND (if first doesn't show because it's lazy)

```
2016-01-16 08:53:55     DEBUG views 3: [<Person: JOHN SMITH>, <Person: GEORGE WASHINGTON>, <Person: ABRAHAM LINCOLN>, <Person: PARIS HILTON>, <Person: JOHN WAYNE>, <Person: TEST TEST>
```

or just crash if something is wrong with this debug?

**UPDATE**
I leave the whole example, for the next, because sometimes its hard to point, that problem is with one letter - so this can help others.

Answer (score 1):

Finally found!

http://codestrian.com/index.php/2015/06/26/a-guide-to-setting-up-django-logging-on-linux/

```
  'rotate_file':{
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'class': 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
            'filename': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'log/error.log'),
            'formatter': 'verbose',
            'maxBytes': 10485760,
            'backupCount': 20,
            'encoding': 'utf8'
        },
```

and the last line is the most important: **`'encoding': 'utf8'`**